# Static Library Performance - Possible to inline calls?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I've been trying to make an attempt to make a Game Engine, and I started out by making the Mathmatical foundation ( Vector, Matrix and Point classes. )
I would like to make a static library file (.lib) which I can then use in the rest of my Game Engine where it's needed.

What I was wondering is the following. Since most functions in the library need to be as fast as possible. I'd like to see the functions for example a Vector class being inlined. Can the compiler automatically do this? Or is some kind of hint needed?

I know I can put all the source in the header files but I think that's not really an elegant solution since some functions might be too large to be inlined. ( Header files wouldn't kind of be messy for the poeple using them. )

I hope you guys could help me out.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inlining of functions is only guaranteed to work with current compiler technology if the compileunit has visibility of the source code. Once you compile code into a library, it will not inline the function, no matter what the function does.

There is some "whole program optimization" schemes (available in at least MSVC and GCC, probably other compilers too) that produce a "object file" that is only part of the way to machine-code, so that some of the information about "what the source code wanted" is available to the final code-generation/linking stage to move code around, perform inlining and such, but this is only applicable when all source-files are available at the compile-time. Once something is made into final object code (which your static library is), it won't be making it into the "inliner" part.

Obviously, if you have classes, they will be in header files, so if you put functions suitable for inlining into the header file, the compiler will do the right thing.

Comment: So the only possible way to actually make the fastest Math-Library is to make it header-only? And what is the advantage over Whole Program Optimization vs just providing the source files too? I mean if you need the source files for the first one then why not do the second right away?

Comment: I think MSVC is able to inline calls to static library functions, as long as the library is compiled with link time code generation enabled.

Comment: The point of whole program optimisation, with regards to inlining, is just a side-effect of the "optimsing the whole program" technique, where different compile units can be combined together in the final code generation. I don't think you need to make it "header only". Inlining is only of much advantage if the code is very short and fast. Once a function is big enough and takes long enough to run, it is actually BETTER to have it not inlined, since the code is smaller and the chances of the code hitting in the cache is better if it's called from several places.

Comment: Timo, Do you have any sources about if MSVC can inline those calls?

Comment: Mats Peterson, Thanks for your time! That's the first thing I'd like to say. Optimising Whole Program sounds useful. So this means setting it in MSVC for all the projects in the solution would make the calls inline. ( Am I correct? )

Comment: Im coming here since I am playing with trying to wrap windows api with zero overhead; and I came across two realizations; first is that it can be wrapped with a static library that hides  the main, so that WinMain calls another main which only uses c types. But this has the jump overhead since WinMain can't inline the other main since it doesn't know its' source. The other solution is to use macros or a scripting language to inline WinMain into the delegate main file, but this makes Windows.h bring its friends to the global scope. It seems that it is literally impossible without a new language

Comment: that is, the new language being C which treats different named structs with same data to be interchangeable; as it stands it doesn't, which is inconsistent with other c primitives.

Comment: In nearly all programs, calling `main` through a call wouldn't really matter. It happens ONCE, and loading a program in the first place is some thousands or maybe even millions of clock-cycles (even longer if it loads from a network filesystem or other slow storage).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with *link time optimization*. If you generate a "fat" library, it would include both the compiled source and also an intermediate form that can be used to inline functions at link time (essentially, at link time a final compilation step is done, where everything is visible).

The technique is somewhat fragile since you need to ensure you are using the same flags at compile and link time and there are a few other restrictions: it wouldn't be a good way to publicly distribute a library. If it's for a controlled internal use though, it may work well.